# pam_tally2 doesn't count fails over ssh

Tags: ssh, pam

I have added line

```
auth required pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=180
```

to my `/etc/pam.d/login` file, and that's fine and dandy in tty, after 3 attempts `testuser` gets suspended.

However, that very same line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` produces no effect.

```
xieerqi:$ ssh testuser@localhost
Password: 
Password: 
Password: 
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

xieerqi:$ ssh testuser@localhost                                                                                           
Password: 
Password: 
Password: 
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

As you can see after 3 unsuccessful attempts, the user still can attempt entering password.

How do I make `ssh` ban a user after 3 strikes?

Comment: Could it be that `ssh` is not PAM-ified (compiled with PAM library)?

Answer (score 2):

For SSH it might be better to use something different than pam there is a great solution made through iptables and the `sshd_config` file. This is only one way to get what you want, also based on documentation usually it is recommended to use SSH Keys instead of a password authentification method check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring.

1. You would need to change the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` adding the line

   ```
   MaxAuthTries 1
   ```
2. You need to create the following firewall rules

   - Create a new chain

     ```
     iptables -N SSHATTACK   
     iptables -A SSHATTACK -j LOG --log-prefix "Possible SSH attack! " --log-level 7  
     iptables -A SSHATACK -j DROP
     ```
   - Block each IP address for 120 seconds which establishe more than three connections within 120 seconds. In case of the forth connection attempt, the request gets delegated to the SSHATTACK chain, which is responsible for logging the possible ssh attack and finally drops the request.

     ```
     iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --dport 22 --state NEW -m recent --set     
     iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --dport 22 --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 120 --hitcount 4 -j SSHATTACK
     ```
3. You can check the attempts made on the file `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

The common practice is to use `fail2ban` which works on network level instead of pam level and which saves your resources for all that crypto done by `sshd`.

Anyway, did you try after that failed authentication to insert correct password? Is it accepted? What is logged in `/var/log/auth.log`?

`sshd` server always run all the pam stack even if the user doesn't exist, is suspended or locked to eliminate attacks using side-channels (identification of existing users for example). This is the problem you seems to be hitting. It can work, but you can't see it over `ssh` because of security.

Comment: If I run ` sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep testuser | grep ssh` it does show authentication failure for testuser, but it doesn't ban the testuser as with tty1

Comment: And if I reset counter for the testuser , run couple of test through ssh, it still shows 0 failed attempts with `sudo pam_tally2 -u testuser` :/ Oh, and the correct password is accepted even after multiple fails

Comment: One more question, just for sure: do you have `UsePAM yes` option in your `sshd_config`?

Comment: Yes, I do . I also have `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of lines, PAM execute them 1 by 1

For example:

/etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
auth    required                        pam_tally2.so deny=3 onerr=fail unlock_time=300 debug
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

works for me.